# Ionic fails to load angular.min.js.map

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when im running my Ionic app inside iOS simulator,
and using the Safari Web inspector, i see this error:

```
file:///.../.../Application/.../myApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/angular.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?
Thanks.

```
  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Libraries -->
  <script src="lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ng-lodash/build/ng-lodash.min.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/constants.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your index.html

Comment: why are you including angular separately? just include `ionic.bundle.js` it is concatenation of  ionic.js, angular.js, angular-animate.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-ui-router.js, and ionic-angular.js.

Comment: strange, i am not including angular explicitly...

Comment: weird stuff. Can you check if there is any file `angular.min.js.map` in ionic lib folder?

Comment: Indeed weird, i just replaced ionic.bundle.min.js with ionic.bundle.js and got rid of the issue.....

Answer (score 1):

I ended up importing ionic.bundle.js instead of ionic.bundle.min.js and the issue was gone